# Ember js get array index of clicked element in an each loop, and filter with it

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to implement the following:

1. My controller returns an array of posts, which fall into a certain category. I am displaying the titles of each of those posts on the left hand side of the page.
2. On the right side of the page, I would like to display an area where the full text of only one post displays. This would be the first post initially, but would change when a different post title is clicked.

I am currently trying to achieve this using two each helpers in my template:

templates/posts.hbs

```html
<div class='left-section'>
  {{#each categoryOnePosts as |post|}}
    <a {{action 'updateFullText'}}>{{post.title}}</a>
  {{/each}}
</div>
<div class='right-section'>
  {{#each currentPostFullText as |post|}} 
   {{post.full_text}} 
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

My idea is to for the 'updateFullText' action to get the array index of a post which is is clicked, and then display only the post which matches that index in the right hand section.

controllers/posts.js

```js
categoryOnePosts: function() {
    var allPosts = this.get('posts');
    var categoryOne = posts.filterBy("category", 1);
    return categoryOne;
  }.property("posts.@each"),

  currentPostFullText: function() {
    var currentPostIndex = this.get('currentPostIndex');
    var categoryOne = this.get('categoryOnePosts');
    var thisPost = //Set thisPost to only include the object at position 'currentPostIndex' in the categoryOne array.
    return thisPost;
  }.property("categoryOnePosts', 'currentPost'),

  actions: {
    var clickedPostIndex = //Get the array index of the clicked item.
    this.set('currentPostIndex', clickedPostIndex);
  },
```

Problem is I can't manage to get the array index of the clicked item. 
Is it possible to achieve this, or would I need to go about this in a completely different way?

Comment: Im little confused here. Quoting "On the right side of the page, I would like to display an area where the full text of only one post displays". Yet you're using {{#each}} helper on right-section'

Comment: I suspect this is far from the most efficient way of going about this- the idea is that the {{each}} helper on the right would only have one item to loop over, as the array would have been filtered to match only one object.

Comment: Seems like there are better ways, added an answer to lose that hackiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your goal- left side categorised items, right side- first categorised item initially. However if user selects a post to see, then it changes to selection.

**| POST 1  category 1|**         --- content ---          **|Categorised list 1st item OR Selection of post|**

### **| POST 2 category  1|**

Where posts are filtered By some category . for instance category=1

```
selectedCategory: 1,

categorisedPosts: function() {
    return this.get('posts').filterBy("category", this.get('selectedCategory'));
}.property("posts.@each", "selectedCategory"),
```

> This would be the first post initially

```
 activePost: null, // user has not yet clicked for new post
 activeListItem: function() {
    // 1st post or selected post.
    return Ember.isPresent('activePost') ? this.get('activePost') : this.get('categorisedPosts').get('firstObject')
  }.property('categorisedPosts', 'activePost')

actions: {
   // Activating new POST to be shown on the rights side.
   updateFullText: function(post) {
     this.set('activePost', post);  
   }
}
```

---

```
    <div class='left-section'>
      {{#each categorisedPosts as |post|}}
        <a {{action 'updateFullText' post}}></a>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div class='right-section'>
      {{activeListItem.full_text}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a much better solution than my attempt. I couldn't get the first item to display at for a while, but then I changed 
`return Ember.isPresent('activePost') ?`
to
`return Ember.isPresent(this.get('activePost')) ?`.
Now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: @AJP Im glad it worked out for you. Any code needs explanation or everything is clear as water =) ?

Comment: Thank you- everything is clear! It's great to now know about the `return *** ? *** : ***` syntax to return based on a conditional. Is it possible to set a property (eg 'isActive', true) on the clicked item in the updateFullText action? Thus far, I have only been able to do this by putting the anchor tag in a component as shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084416/ember-js-controlling-class-bindings-in-repeating-component/33085423#33085423).

Comment: Yes "?" syntax is really useful . For instance var x = condition ? saveFunction() : return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(value);
 });. I will give my answer soon

Answer (score 2):

You can access the index property in an `{{#each}}` loop in the following way:

```
<div class='left-section'>
  {{#each categoryOnePosts as |post index|}}
    <a {{action 'updateFullText' index}}>{{post.title}}</a>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

You can then just pass that `index` value to your action and do whatever you need to from there.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that, but was only passing index to the action, not the each helper, and so was getting undefined. Working great now.