# Ember js controlling class bindings in repeating component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a component which is repeating inside an each loop. The component simply displays the title of a post (There could potentially be hundreds).

The code below is successfully adding the class 'active' to a title element which is clicked.

How can I remove class 'active' from all previous titles when a new one is clicked (So that only one title ever has the class active)?

I originally tried doing this on the controller, but I couldn't work out how to set the isActive property on one instance in the each loop.

Template.hbs:

```html
{#each posts as |post index item|}}
  {{title-component data=post index=index}}
{{/each}}
```

title-component.hbs:

```html
<a {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}{{action 'setActive' index}}>{{data.title}}</a>
```

title-component.js

```js
actions: {
  setActive: function(index) {
    this.set('isActive', true);
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you made a workaround for your logics : 
[Ember js get array index of clicked element in an each loop, and filter with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079346/ember-js-get-array-index-of-clicked-element-in-an-each-loop-and-filter-with-it)

I made activeness based on it.

```
updateFullText: function(post) {
     this.set('activePost.isActive', false); // First lose previous activeness

     this.set('activePost', post); // Active post gets re-valuated

     this.set('activePost.isActive', true);  // Activate new item
}




   <div class="left-section">
      {{#each categorisedPosts |as| post}}
        <span class="{{if post.isActive 'activeClass'}}> {{post.description}} </span>
     {{/each}}
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much- I can see clearly how this will work. One small snag though- because **activePost** is initially set to null, the first run of the action gives the error **Property set failed: object in path "activePost" could not be found or was destroyed.** Is it possible to set the first object in the array to be activePost when the route is entered?

Comment: Sure, yeah i also saw the issue =D Changing in a second

Comment: I'm not using a component in the each loop anymore, so I'm not sure if **didInsertElement** can help?

Comment: @AJP Oh year, totally forgot about it. Let me think of a better one.

Comment: What about **.on(init)**? A function along the lines of:
`if (activePost === null) {Set first object in the categorisedPosts array to be activePost, and set isActive to true on that object}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92153/discussion-between-kristjan-reinhold-and-ajp).

Answer (score 0):

You could set activeness in many ways. But considering you already done some work, I'll just slightly improve your solution. You can define isActive property in TitleComponent as computed property that depends on 'activeIndex' variable from controller.

So, define 'activeIndex' property in controller:

```
activeIndex: null
```

Then, define isActive property in TitleCompoenent:

```
isActive: Ember.equal('activeIndex', 'index')
```

Then, pass the 'global' variable to each component:

```
{#each posts as |post index item|}}
  {{title-component data=post index=index activeIndex=activeIndex}}
{{/each}}
```

And change activeIndex value in 'setActive' action in TitleComponent:

```
actions: {
  setActive: function(index) {
    this.set('activeIndex', index);
  },
}
```

P.S. Please, consider to wipe out 'bind-attr' helper. It's been deprecated  a long ago.